# Where do I post question about why git-scm.com is not accessible (down)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The site [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com) currently times out. I'd like to know what's going on. Google chrome displays the following:

> No data received
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Is there a Stack Exchange site can I ask about this? Or, are there other known sites on the Internet that can give hints about what may be causing it, the status of the problem, etc.?

I can't contact the site directly in this case as the home page is not accessible.

Comment: The downvote is because someone downvoted you. What reasons I cannot tell you, but the fact is it could be many things. Asking where to post something which does not fit on any site; ;Lack of research; Not helpful; Not well written; Bad tags used; etc etc

Comment: I don't expect a direct answer to my question. I've edited my question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Questions about external resources are off-topic on all stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The site git-scm.com currently times out. I'd like to know what's
>   going on

This site you've asked on is about managing all Stack sites in the network, so you cannot ask that question here, and all other sites in the Stack Exchange network are not for asking things like "why is this website down". How can someone other than the people who manage the site tell you what is wrong?

Contact the site in question and see what they say.

Also, try this:
http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://git-scm.com/

It's not just you, so there's nothing anyone can do, or tell you really. The site is down. I'm sure the site admins are working on it.

Comment: The site itself is down, so it's not possible to contact it.

Comment: So what can anyone else do if the site is down and cannot go to it or email them? I've edited my answer to include a useful link. I wasn;t being funny, there's no more others can do than yourself really, using the above link, or ping etc

Answer (score 9):

There is no Stack Exchange site for this, because this type of question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Sites can be down for any reason; often only the site maintainers know why (or are desperately trying to find out why...)

But this is a temporary issue. The site may be up a few hours later, in which case the question no longer has relevance. Or the site may have gone down for good, in which case the question is also largely irrelevant.

Answers on Stack Exchange must be useful for the future, and it must be possible for the community to judge them, so that they can upvote or downvote accordingly. Neither condition applies to "why is example.com down", so this is not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

However, current events can be discussed in the relevant Stack Exchange chat; if you find a chatroom that is open to this kind of question, you can ask your question there.